# Sends a personalised error message from the back-end to the front-end with Nuxt-auth

Tags: authentication, error-handling, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Depending on the error in my back-end, I would like to display the corresponding error in my front-end, for example if an email address or a pseudo is already use in my DB (I work with nuxt-auth local provider)
At the moment, my custom message is displayed in my editor console like this: [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] E-mail adrress already use !

But in my console browser have an 500 (Internal Server Error) from POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register

Btw if I enter an address that is not yet known, my code works

```
//register.post.ts 

export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    let e;
    const response = await readBody(event);
    console.log(response);
    const userEmail = response.email;
    const searchMailIntoDB = await client.query(`SELECT mail
                                                 from profil
                                                 where mail = '${userEmail}'`);
    const isEmailExist = searchMailIntoDB.rows[0];
    const userPseudo = response.pseudo;
    const searchPseudoIntoDB = await client.query(`SELECT pseudo
                                                   from profil
                                                   where mail = '${userPseudo}'`);
    const isPseudoExist = searchPseudoIntoDB.rows[0];
    if (isEmailExist) {
        throw new Error("E-mail address already in use!");
    } else if (isPseudoExist) {
        throw new Error("Pseudo already in use!");
    } else {
        console.log("Create new account..");
    }
});

//connexion.vue 

async function signUpWithCredentials() {
  const credentials = {
    email: signUpEmail.value,
    password: signUpPassword.value,
    firstName: firstName.value,
    lastName: lastName.value,
    gender: gender.value,
    pseudo: pseudo.value
  };
  try {
    await signUp(credentials, {callbackUrl: '/allPosts', redirect: true, external: true});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```